# Change printed variable names for summary()

Tags: r, variables, summary

I am using `summary()` to create a, yes, summary from my regression. What now is printed is my variable names, including underscore.

Is there any way to change the printed variable names so that I can see e.g. "Age of dog" instead of `dog_age`.

I can not change the variable names since they can not contain spaces.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
> x <- summary(lm(mpg ~ cyl+wt, mtcars))
> rownames(x$coef) <- c("YOUR", "NAMES", "HERE")
> x$coef

#       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# YOUR   39.6863     1.7150  23.141  < 2e-16 
# NAMES  -1.5078     0.4147  -3.636 0.001064 
# HERE   -3.1910     0.7569  -4.216 0.000222
```

Or you could just change the names in the data before running regression

```
> names(mtcars)[1:3] <- rownames(x$coef)
> lm(YOUR ~ NAMES+HERE, mtcars)

# Call:
# lm(formula = YOUR ~ NAMES + HERE, data = mtcars)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)        NAMES         HERE  
#    34.66099     -1.58728     -0.02058
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `backtick` **`** to introduce spaces in variables:

```
dat = data.frame(`Age of dog`=1:10,`T`=1:10,check.names=FALSE)
summary(lm(T~`Age of dog`,data=dat))
```